# Displaying return value from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a function that takes in two parameters and returns the sum.

Now I'm trying ti create an form that takes in two numbers. When button is clicked it should call the function sum and display the sum of these two numbers. **What is the best way to display the return value?**

My code so far:

```
<form>
        <input type="number" id="firstnumber"/>
        <input type="number" id="secondnumber"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="summa(document.getElementById(firstnumber),document.getElementById(secondnumber))" id="Summa" value="Calculate sum"/>
    </form>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
document.write(document.getElementById(Summa))
</script>
    </div>
```

**The function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function summa(number1, number2)
        {
            var sum = number1 + number2;
            return sum;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide your `summa()` implementation just for good measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things a little wonky about what you're doing. Firstly, you aren't passing the **values** from the inputs to your function; you're passing the **elements** themselves. Secondly, in the attempt to write the value to the document you are again referencing an element and not the element's value. Lastly, you would be attempting to add together the elements (or their string values, if you were retrieving them), which would only concatenate together into a new string instead of performing the actual math.

**This is my approach to really cleaning up and fixing your attempt:**

First, let's get rid of the ugly and obtrusive onclick event handler altogether (we'll wire up the event handler differently later):

```
<input type="button" id="Summa" value="Calculate sum"/>
```

Add a third input so we can display the sum:

```
<input type="text" id="sumnumber" />
```

And now let's do all the JavaScript work in one place, as the last thing before your closing `</body>` tag. This keeps the HTML clean and not littered with inline JavaScript, so you don't have to dig through it when you need to make changes.

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Your new summing function definition that takes input values
        function summa(valueOne, valueTwo) {
            // Convert the strings to numbers before doing the math
            return Number(valueOne) + Number(valueTwo);
        }

        // Now let's hold onto some references to the elements in the page
        var sumButton = document.getElementById('Summa');
        var firstNumber = document.getElementById('firstnumber');
        var secondNumber = document.getElementById('secondnumber');
        var sumNumber = document.getElementById('sumnumber');

        // Wire up the event
        sumButton.onclick = function() {
            // Re-use the variables outside of this scope to retrieve 
            var sum = summa(firstNumber.value, secondNumber.value);
            // Update the sum element with the result of the function
            sumNumber.value = sum.toString();
        };

    </script>
</body>
```

Here's a working **<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5NZGB/2/)</kbd>**.

**Note:** If this were going to be production code and not just a teaching example, there are other things I would do, including: (1) number validation, and (2) lock down the inputs (maxlength, etc.) and outputs (update to a `<span>` or similar), among other minor things.

Comment: The function should accept two parameters. So it can't "pull" firstnumber and secondnumber in the function. Can't I do that outside of the function, and use that as parameters for the function?

Comment: @user3265963: I know I've been editing like crazy, but I simplified my original answer down to just one final concrete example.